# From where did celerybeat gets it configuration shown during its startup

Tags: python, django, celerybeat

When I start celerybeat by `manage.py celerybeat` I see this:

```
[2011-07-12 13:37:46,892: WARNING/MainProcess] __    -    ... __   -        _
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqplib://guest@localhost:5672/
    . loader -> djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@INFO
    . maxinterval -> 1 hour (3600.0s)
[2011-07-12 13:37:46,892: INFO/MainProcess] Celerybeat: Starting...
```

I want to know which file it got the above configuration from.

I want to change the database for celery to be MySQL. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I want to chnage the database for celery to be mysql. how can i do that".  Celery isn't using a database, it's using a messaging queue.  In your case most likely RabbitMQ.

Celery takes it's config from your project's settings.py file.

Comment: I have put these settings `CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = "mysql://user1:project@localhost/amount_rabbitmq"` and `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database"`  . i have read from docs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the broker or you want mysql to handle your task, not rabbitmq, try this in your settings

```
BROKER_URL = 'sqla+mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo'
```

CELERY_RESULT_DBURI is config for location of the result when task run